# removeClass does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying for the life of me to figure out how to get it to remove a class when clicking another link. I want it so it only highlights the specific area selected but the remove class isn't removing the class. So it stays highlighted as specified in the class `underNavselected`. Can anyone assist?

This is all on one page, not linking to other docs. I am hiding and unhiding content with each click.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".toTop").hide();
    jQuery(".aboutHeader").hide();
    jQuery(".LAM").hide();
    jQuery(".WID").hide();
    jQuery(".MyG").hide();
    jQuery("#LAMlink").live("click", function()
    {
        jQuery(this).addClass("underNavselected");
        jQuery(".LAM").slideToggle(500);
        jQuery(".WID").hide();
        jQuery(".MyG").hide();
        jQuery("#MyGlink", "#WIDlink").removeClass("underNavselected");
    });
    jQuery("#WIDlink").live("click", function()
    {
        jQuery(this).addClass("underNavselected");
        jQuery(".WID").slideToggle(500);
        jQuery(".LAM").hide();
        jQuery(".MyG").hide();
        jQuery("#LAMlink", "#MyGlink").removeClass("underNavselected");
    });
    jQuery("#MyGlink").live("click", function()
    {
        jQuery(this).addClass("underNavselected");
        jQuery(".MyG").slideToggle(500);
        jQuery(".LAM").hide();
        jQuery(".WID").hide();
        jQuery("#LAMlink", "#WIDlink").removeClass("underNavselected");
    });
});
```

Comment: Any chance of seeing the markup?

Comment: Don't use `live`. It's deprecated and removed in 1.9. Delegate with `on`.

Comment: I guess some html, or preferably a JSbin won't hurt!?

Comment: @NabilKadimi I'd prefer JSFiddle instead of JSbin

Comment: I meant to say JSFiddle too...

Comment: As an aside, you don't show your html, but I suspect that with a few minor changes to it you could easily combine those three click handlers into a single  more generic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incidentally used a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) your code was equivelent to "#LAMlink #WIDlink" which means you are looking for a WIDlink that has an ancestor of LAMlink

So the proper solution is to change:

```
jQuery("#LAMlink", "#WIDlink")
```

to

```
jQuery("#LAMlink, #WIDlink")
```

Notice mine is all the same `string.`

Comment: How do you know he doesn't want the `#LAMlink` that is inside `#WIDlink`? :-)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I can't believe it was that slight misstep.

Comment: @JanDvorak, IDs should be unique and a context shouldn't be needed, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5611975/358906

Comment: @NabilKadimi - ignoring the fact that Jan was kidding, even with unique IDs you might sometimes want to select an element with a particular ID only if it is a descendent of a certain other element.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
jQuery("#MyGlink, #WIDlink").removeClass("underNavselected");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
  jQuery("#MyGlink", "#WIDlink").removeClass("underNavselected");
```

To this:

```
  jQuery("#MyGlink, #WIDlink").removeClass("underNavselected");
```

And similar in each place that you do that.

The selector should be a single string with commas in it. The way you had it jQuery will look for elements matching the first selector that are descendents of elements matching the second selector.